# ffmpeg to Youtube Live stops working. ffmpeg continues to run

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I'm streaming a mobotix camera to Youtube Live.

This works correctly for a period of time. Youtube then reports the stream as "noData".
ffmpeg continues to run, but no video is being received by Youtube.

The problem is intermittant.

Restarting the ffmpeg process makes Youtube start receiving the stream again.

ffmpeg is being run as a systemd service.

ffmpeg is run with the following command:

`ffmpeg -nostdin  -f lavfi  -i anullsrc  -rtsp_transport tcp -thread_queue_size 512 -i "rtsp://@192.168.1.1:554/mobotix.h264"   -tune zerolatency  -vcodec libx264  -pix_fmt + -c:v copy  -c:a aac  -strict experimental  -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/`

Logs only show: `ffmpeg[47357]: [48.0K blob data]`

Any ideas on how to solve this? Or improve the logging.

Edit:
Logs from starting ffmpeg:

```
    Feb 07 17:57:00 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]: [48.0K blob data]
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:       encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:     Metadata:
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:     Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1024x768, q=2-31, 12.50 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:     encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   Metadata:
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]: Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/':
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 (native) -> aac (native))
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Feb 07 17:52:47 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]: Stream mapping:
    Feb 07 17:52:46 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:     Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1024x768, 12.50 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Feb 07 17:52:46 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   Duration: N/A, start: 136.139322, bitrate: N/A
    Feb 07 17:52:46 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:     comment         : mobotix.h264
    Feb 07 17:52:46 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:     title           : Mobotix IP-Camera (H.264, unicast)
    Feb 07 17:52:46 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   Metadata:
    Feb 07 17:52:46 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]: Input #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://@192.168.1.1:554/mobotix.h264':
    Feb 07 17:52:44 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]: [h264 @ 0x559ee7857940] concealing 2400 DC, 2400 AC, 2400 MV errors in P frame
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:     Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]: Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 >
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]:   built with gcc 8 (GCC)
    Feb 07 17:52:43 localhost.localdomain ffmpeg[49525]: ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
```

Running the command manually gave me logs and exited, whereas the systemd service keeps running.

```
    [flv @ 0x560541a8b3c0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
    av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipekB time=03:35:18.84 bitrate=3131.8kbits/s speed=0.999x    
        Last message repeated 1 times
    [flv @ 0x560541a8b3c0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
    [flv @ 0x560541a8b3c0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
    Error writing trailer of rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/: Broken pipe
    frame=134427 fps= 10 q=-1.0 Lsize= 4938869kB time=03:35:18.96 bitrate=3131.8kbits/s speed=0.997x    
    video:4923745kB audio:3296kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.240068%
    [aac @ 0x560541a6d680] Qavg: 65536.000
    Conversion failed!
```

Comment: It works for a time. As mentioned the logs just show blob data other than the start up. I've added the start up logs

Comment: Unfortunately that's an incomplete output from ffmpeg so it isn't very helpful.

Comment: Running the command manually gave me logs and exited, whereas the systemd service keeps running.